# Run .js file from another .js file?

Tags: javascript, imacros

If I have two .js file one next to another and they are named like this:

```
- jsmacro1.js
- jsmacro2.js
```

How do I run jsmacro2.js from jsmacro1.js ? I tried with this:

```
iimPlay("C:\\example\\jsmacro2.js",60)
```

but got error  `jsmacro1.js.iim not found`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try this:

```
iimPlayCode("URL GOTO=imacros://run/?m=Test1.js");
```

Comment: I thought so. But can you run .js file from batch ? Are there any working examples ?