# Pass parameter to bookmarklet through url

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, bookmarklet, imacros

I'm currently customizing my browser using iMacro for firefox, in conjunction with instantfox quicksearch.

The quicksearch allows you to use a hotkey and a parameter, which is molded into a url.

example "m google" gives me "imacros://run/?m=google.iim" in the adress bar, starting the macro called "google".

Now I want to add a variable ( "m google(var)" ), but I'm at a loss on how to call a local javascript function through a url.

I know javascript can be stored in bookmarklets, but how can those be accessed, and called with a parameter,  through a url?

Are there any other way to convert hotkeys to url, than instantfox? I'd like to be able to use multiple parametres ("m google var")

Answer (score 0):

You have the answer here. [Run .js file from another .js file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19159742/run-js-file-from-another-js-file)

Also you can use this to convert any imacros into url.

http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/imacros-codegen/

Comment: Neither is helpful, sorry. I want to be able to call a javascript function through a url, as well as pass a parameter to the function. The first one is just calling a script from a script, the other one requires you to pass the code, with variable, through a program, which isn't exactly time-efficient.